# why limit to number of posts downloadable?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, numbers, limit, posts

I am not able to download all pots in a wall. I have mentioned 99999 as the limit, but it stops anywhere between 150 to 300!!
Why is that?

eg /some_page_id/feeds

it returns different number of posts for different pages, and never do I het all the posts?
Anyone knows why?

Comment: Cause facebook doesn't want everybody and their pet monkey tying up its bandwidth downloading 100000 posts at once?  Particularly considering most people will never read them all...

Answer (score 2):

Because like most of the apis out there clients have quotas. same thing for tweeter or netflix or else, because when you request something you are draining facebook bandwith or tweeter's bandwith ,so it make sense for them to limit the amount of request you can do.